# Open Image From FileChooser On a Button

Tags: javafx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV3hP.png)I need help I want to open a Image with a button of browse using filechooser on javafx ? how can I do it?

```
 FileChooser f;
File file;
Image img;
ImageView mv;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{

    f = new FileChooser();
    Button browse = new Button("Browse");

    browse.setOnAction((event) -> 
    {
         file = f.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
         img  = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
         mv   = new ImageView(img);

    });
         mv.setImage(img);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setTop(browse);
    root.setCenter(mv);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Note that the event handler is executed after the method setting it completes. This means there is not only the problem of the `file` variable being created in a in a scope not accessible from said method but also the problem of the file not being chosen at the time the image constructor is invoked. At least the creation of the `Image` instance needs to be moved to the event handler. Depending on the desired look of the scene before choosing the image you may or may not want to move the `ImageView` creation to the handler too. (`ImageView.setImage` can be used in the latter case.)

Comment: still i am having nullpointerexception. I have updated my code kindly check it. I really need help, I have a big project.

Comment: If the answer helped solve your problem, click the check under the down 
 arrow to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` method sets up the scene and shows the window. It completes before the button handler is run and the information you get during it's execution is not available at this time. You need to do modify the scene with the image from the event handler for this reason:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final FileChooser f = new FileChooser();
    final ImageView mv = new ImageView(); // create empty ImageView
    Button browse = new Button("Browse");

    browse.setOnAction((event) -> {
         File file = f.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
         if (file != null) { // only proceed, if file was chosen
             Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
             mv.setImage(img);
         }

    });

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setTop(browse);
    root.setCenter(mv);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Alternatively you could create the `ImageView` in the event handler and place it in the scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final FileChooser f = new FileChooser();
    Button browse = new Button("Browse");
    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    browse.setOnAction((event) -> {
         File file = f.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
         if (file != null) { // only proceed, if file was chosen
             Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
             ImageView mv = new ImageView(img);
             root.setCenter(mv); // add ImageView to scene
         }

    });

    root.setTop(browse);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend it is solved now .
May God bless you :-)